# Android ListView with XML entries won't select an item

Tags: android, android-listview

I've got a ListView with static content (defined as a string array resource, set with `android:entries` in the view).

Setting `choiceMode` seems to do nothing. Selection events don't seem to trigger. If i set a selected index from the click handler, it doesn't sick: if i try to get the selected index immediately after, i get -1.

EDIT: Now that I'm not on my phone:

List definition in XML:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/actions_list"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:entries="@array/actions_listItems" />
```

In the activity's onCreate

```
final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.actionRequired_list);

list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View target, int position, long rowId) {
        Log.i("LIST_EVENT", "item selected: pos = " + position + "; id = " + rowId);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        Log.i("LIST_EVENT", "item deselected");
    }
});
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {
        view.setSelected(true);
         Log.i("LIST_EVENT", "item clicked: pos = " + position + "; id = " + rowId);

    }
});
```

I get "item clicked" just fine, but neither selected nor deselected works.

Comment: Do you mind showing your code? It will help everyone understand the issue better

Comment: Sorry, originally posted from my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Selected" does not mean what I assumed it meant. Selected is more like "focused". What I wanted was "checked".

Forget about `setOnItemSelectedListener`, try this instead

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {
            final int oldSelection = list.getCheckedItemPosition();
            list.setItemChecked(position, true);
            Log.i("LIST_EVENT", "item clicked: pos = " + position + "; id = " + rowId);
            Log.i("LIST_EVENT", "post-item clicked report: old selection = " + oldSelection + "; new = " + list.getCheckedItemPosition());
    }
});
```

Notice:

- `list.setItemChecked(position, true)` not `list.setSelection(position)`
- `list.getCheckedItemPosition()` not `list.getSelectedItemPosition()`

And to make the checked item be visibly selected, I used this instead of setting `android:entries`:

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked,
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.actionRequired_listItems));

list.setAdapter(aa);
```